# Preview PDF in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way to view A PDF file in access?  I am storing the path to the file in the database and am able to open it from a button in the database, but I'd like to be able to show a preview of it as well.

Comment: As in a show it in a control on a form?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you would be able to do this with a raw pdf file, however you could have your application take the first page of the pdf and save it as an image file that you could then load as the preview.

Comment: That is not true. A PDF can be displayed in an unbound OLE control in Access.

Comment: @Remou Fair enough, I simply don't have enough experience with that :(